# Does dolphindb support a function which is similar to the function dropna?

Tags: python, dolphindb

Does dolphindb support a function which is similar to the function dropna in python?

Is there a dropna function which is similar to the one in python to remove the columns contains Nan?

I want to realize the featrues like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data_without_NaN =df.dropna(axis=1)
print (data_without_NaN)
```

Comment: You should explain what the Python function does specifically - how can people who are familiar with DolphinDB but not Python answer this question without knowing what the function does? Are you expecting them to research `dropna` themselves to learn what it does in order to try to help you?

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB provides dropna function as well, the example is shown following:

```py
x=1 NULL 2 3 NULL NULL 4;
x.dropna();
=>[1,2,3,4]
m=matrix(1 1 1 1, 1 1 1 NULL, 1 NULL 1 NULL);
dropna(m);
```

The result is：

| #0 | #1 | #2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

You can control the deletion of rows or columns with NULL values ​​through the [byRow](https://www.dolphindb.cn/cn/help/130/Functionalprogramming/TemplateFunctions/byRow.html) function.